# List box is not scrolling to last item

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am developing a Windows Phone 8 application, in that I am using List box to display the data. I have requirement like once the page is launched user should navigate to the last item of the list box. For this requirement used scroolintoview method like LsbSample.ScrollIntoView(LsbSample.LastOrDefault). It is moving to the last item but not fully. It is showing last item around 60% but for remaining 40% I need to manually scroll the list box.

Can any one help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this code

```
scroll_content.UpdateLayout();
scroll_content.ScrollToVerticalOffset(double.MaxValue);
```

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a6e3f3b6-44db-4201-828a-af7fffa7219e/scrollviewer-force-scroll-to-bottom?forum=silverlightnet

Comment: Hi Jestiin, Thanks for the response. I am using list box not list view and scrollViewer.ScrollToBottom method is not available.

Comment: try changing listview to listbox

Comment: I just changed from ListView to Listbox but ScrollToBottom is not available for scrollViewer.

Comment: try this scroll_content.UpdateLayout();

scroll_content.ScrollToVerticalOffset(double.MaxValue);